# Google Cloud Function us-central time zone?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'd like to know what timezone cloud function code would run like EST, CST, MST, PST something like this.
I deployed function to get it but it returned `2018-12-05T17:54:00.207Z` and not applying any US timezone. Is it not running in US?

```
 export const dateLog = functions.https.onRequest((_, response) => {
    const date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
    response.send(date);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the string form of the Date object to show a certain timezone?  If you need to render a point in time in a particular timezone, you should use a library to format it the way you need.

Comment: I just wanna know local time where function executed.

Comment: Again, why does it matter? You already have a guarantee what city the data center is in. Each function has a region, and the city in that region is known. This means you know the local TZ. But I can't imagine how that data is useful for whatever your function needs to do.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. What I want to do is refresh quote every morning at 6AM. So I need to calculate time differences to refresh the quote in every different county. Does that make sense?

Comment: 6AM whose time?  If you have users around the world, not everyone will have the same timezone.  Anyway, fetching the date inside a function will not help you schedule this refresh at a give time.  It will just tell you the point in time that's common for all people everywhere on earth.

Comment: @Daibaku If you want to trigger your HTTPS Cloud Function you will most probably use an online Cron job like https://cron-job.org/en/. It is there that you have to configure the different calls to the Function according to the different time zones, and not in the Cloud Function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's UTC. I tried `print(datetime.now())` and got a UTC timestamp.