# Google Cloud Functions reports incorrect date with new Date()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using a formatted date string (YYYYMMDD) to determine if certain content should be provided to a user. When I deploy and run my function for/from firebase, it reports the correct date early in the day (when I generally do my development...animal I know) and it incorrectly reports late at night.

I guess that it is using GMT and not EDT but it should at least be based on the server location (us-central1) or even where the user is (Eastern) but shouldn't be off by over 2 hours, right?

Here is a boiled-down version of the code...

```
exports.manageQuestionList = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}/questions/{questionId}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

  // Prepare a number that represents today's date
  let theDate = new Date()
  theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate())

  let yearString = String(theDate.getFullYear())
  let monthString = String(theDate.getMonth()+1)
  if (monthString.length === 1) {
      monthString = '0' + monthString
  }
  let dayString = String(theDate.getDate())
  if (dayString.length === 1) {
      dayString = '0' + dayString
  }

  let dayID = yearString + monthString + dayString

  console.log(dayID)

}
```

Right now it is 22:41 in the Eastern Time zone on July 29 in 2019... The result is expected to be 20190729. This gives a result to the log of 20190730 however.

Edit: Thanks for the help! Is there somewhere in the documents I might have figured this out on my own? I'll have to test this again tonight but when I run from nearly identical code on the client-side (shown below) it returns one date/time and when I run on a function, it is the next day (late at night).

```
export const getDayID = (addDays) => {


    if (!addDays) {
        addDays = 0
    }

    // Prepare a number that represents today's date
    let theDate = new Date()
    theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + addDays)

    let yearString = String(theDate.getFullYear())
    let monthString = String(theDate.getMonth()+1)
    if (monthString.length === 1) {
        monthString = '0' + monthString
    }
    let dayString = String(theDate.getDate())
    if (dayString.length === 1) {
        dayString = '0' + dayString
    }

    let dayID = yearString + monthString + dayString

    return dayID


}
```

Comment: It seems Cloud Functions run in GMT. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638205/google-cloud-function-us-central-time-zone

Answer (score 0):

The date is almost certainly working correctly.  If the system's sense of date was off, Google Cloud services would be extremely unreliable, as nothing would be able to synchronize correctly.

Instead of depending on the system's sense of timezone, or speculating about what it ought to be, you should instead apply your own formatting rules based on a timezone of your explicit choice.  This means you should be using a library such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) along with its companion library [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to take full control of that.