# React getTimezoneOffset disparity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm getting different timezone offsets from different files in the same app.

Component:

```
let date = new Date()
let offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() // 360 (my timezone but in the past)
```

Firebase function (only exists locally):

```
let date = new Date()
let offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() // 0
```

Why???

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions are server-side code, that all run in UTC. But even if they'd run in another timezone, you can't expect that to be the same timezone as your client-side code.

This is actually why it's great that `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the correct result; you can use this to show the time on the server, in the timezone of the client as needed.

Also see:

- [Google Cloud Function us-central time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638205/google-cloud-function-us-central-time-zone)
- And this more thorough [test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2253#issuecomment-631558931) by one of the engineers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Can you edit your question to show what you get as output (and the code of how you get that output)?